# Newbie UIPickerview Array/Dictionary advice needed

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Best way to populate a UIPickerView with static data and key?

Example:

I want UIPickerview to have text values of:
"Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" .....

And return values of:
"1", "2", "3"......

Do I have to use a NSDictionary or can I do this with a simple NSArray?

Comment: If the values are "continuous", you just can use the `row` (and add+1 to the value) in `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` and use a simple `NSArray` with your days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary would have two entries - one for "display", and one for "value". Based on the row index you grab the dictionary from the array. Use the "display" key when populating the picker view and use the "value" key to return the desired value to the user.

Or simply use the chosen row index to calculate the return value such as:

```
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowIndex + 1];
```